# Select and delete duplicate records with specific id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL db of 600.000 records with auto increment id.
I insert 20.000 more records with an id over 700.000.

I would like to get the id of the inserted records (ie id>700000) which have a duplicate 'field1' value.

I try:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table 
WHERE id>700000 
AND field1 IN (SELECT field1 FROM my_table WHERE id<700000)
```

This request doesn't run... after 1 hour waiting I still don't have any result.

Usually when I want to suppress duplicate I do that:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX(field1)
```

But if I do that I'm not sure which duplicate row it will delete. I must not delete those which have id<700000...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can just do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select field1, group_concat(id) as ids
from my_table
group by field1
having min(id) < 700000 and max(id) > 700000;
```

Or, if you only want ids greater than 700000, then use:

```
group_concat(case when id > 700000 then id end) as ids
```

You can use your method.  I would recommend `exists` rather than `in` and you need an index:

```
SELECT id
FROM my_table t 
WHERE t.id > 700000 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE t2.id < 700000 and t2.field1 = t.field1);
```

Then, you need an index on `my_table(field1, id)` and an index on `my_table(id, field1)` might also be helpful.

Comment: works perfect. just to try to understand, what having min(id)... max(id) is doing ?
And how do you delete these lines... just DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN(SELECT...... your sql method....) ?

Comment: @VincentTeyssier . . . The `min(id)` and `max(id)` are just determining if a given field has ids in both ranges.  For the second part, you should ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Well, "delete" is already in the title of the question so I don't think I should open a new question. But anyway I solved the issue by coding a pho script which stores the result of the select in an array then delete one by one. In term of speed it was very efficient

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join to get the duplicate ids:

```
select *
from my_table t1
inner join my_table t2 on t1.field1=t2.field1
where t1.id<70000 and t2.id>=70000
```

Comment: I'm trying this but 10 mins and still running.... :/ should I have index on something ?

Comment: The id field should be indexed.

Comment: This means you may the same field1 value repeated several times across the 2 populations. If you have the same field1 value in 10 records below 70k and in 10 records above 70k, then in the result you will see 100 records.

Comment: according to one of the method answered above I have 4000 duplicates... should I do a SELECT DISTINCT id instead of * ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` between two instances of your table. And later delete the instance which meets your **condition of deletion**.

```
DELETE t2
FROM my_table t1 
INNER JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
AND t1.id < 700000 AND t2.id >= 700000;
```

**Note:** The `t2` instance holds the records which match the `field1` value with those of records having `id < 700000`. So, deleting `t2` will leave the table devoid of duplicate `field1` values.